# How to access Fields in Outlook message from VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have tried to google around on how to access field in outlook messages (not form fields) from VBA but to no avail.

An illustration of the field: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCfOV.png

Can any one point me to the right direction to search, or can provide me with snippet of code to get started?

I have read [Word 2010 can Field added via QuickParts be given an ID and later referenced in document.Fields collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608038/word-2010-can-field-added-via-quickparts-be-given-an-id-and-later-referenced-in) and learnt that it can be accessed from the Fields object.

Example in Word:

```
For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If InStr("CARMODEL", fld.Code) <> 0 Then
        ''this is the carmodel field
    End If
Next
```

I have tried to use

```
   Dim CurrentMessage As MailItem
   Set CurrentMessage = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
```

to set the active mail item but I couldn't access the Field list.

Thank you!

Sincerely,
James

Answer (score 0):

Is the message being displayed? Inspector.WordEditor will return the Word Document object.